# ORACLE SQL Return only duplicated values (not the original)

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have a database with the following info

```
Customer_id, plan_id, plan_start_dte,
```

Since some customer switch plans, there are customers with several duplicated `customer_id`s, but with different `plan_start_dte`. I'm trying to count how many times a day members switch to the premium plan from any other plan ( `plan_id = 'premium'`).

That is, I'm trying to do roughly this: return all rows with duplicate `customer_id`, except for the original plan (`min(plan_start_dte)`), where `plan_id = 'premium'`, and group them by `plan_start_dte`.

I'm able to get all duplicate records with their count:

```
with plan_counts as (
    select c.*, count(*) over (partition by CUSTOMER_ID) ct
    from   CUSTOMERS c
)
select *
from plan_counts
where ct > 1
```

The other steps have me stuck. First I tried to select everything except the original plan:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS c
where  START_DTE not in (
    select min(PLAN_START_DTE)
    from   CUSTOMERS i
    where  c.CUSTOMER_ID = i.CUSTOMER_ID
)
```

But this failed. If I can solve this I believe all I have to add is an additional condition where `c.PLAN_ID = 'premium'` and then group by date and do a count. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `lag()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             lag(plan_id) over (partition by customer_id order by plan_start_date) as prev_plan_id
      from customers c
     ) c
where prev_plan_id <> 'premium' and plan_id = 'premium';
```

I'm not sure what output you want.  For the number of times this occurs per day:

```
select plan_start_date, count(*)
from (select c.*, lag(plan_id) over (partition by customer_id order by plan_start_date) as prev_plan_id
      from customers c
     ) c
where prev_plan_id <> 'premium' and plan_id = 'premium'
group by plan_start_date
order by plan_start_date;
```

Comment: I get "missing window specification for this function"? is it missing the over statement? Just to clarify, if a user has changed a plan 4 times, and the fourth time is premium I want this to be counted.  Playing around with it a bit it looks like the following gives me what I want (premium plans that are not original)

 select * from
(select c.*, lag(plan_id) over (order by plan_start_dte) as prev_plan_id
      from customer_hist c
      ) c
      WHERE prev_plan_id IS NOT NULL
      AND PLAN_ID = 'premium'

But when I aggregate over it by month the numbers seem high

Comment: Yeah, I'm realizing I'm not using lag the right way. Was trying to use it to somehow flag (with a null value) if there didn't exist a plan prior to each plan for a customer id.